# JWPlayer 6 playlist duration option

Tags: javascript, css, jwplayer, playlist, jwplayer6

I was using JWPlayer 5, but right now moving to JWPlayer 6.

On JWPlayer support [page](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1412123-building-jw-player-skins) you can see that playlist have time duration for each video, but I don't see duration in play list with a code below.

[image]

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("summitplayer").setup({
            height: 1080,
            width: 640,
            listbar: {
                position: 'bottom',
                size: 720
            },
            playlist: [
                { duration: 488, title: "My title #1", description: "Description #1", file: "file1.mp4", image: "file1.png" },
              { duration: 488, title: "My title #2", description: "Description #2", file: "file2.mp4", image: "file2.png" }
            ]
        });
    </script>
```

I am not afraid of using a particular skin or creating a skin for [player](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413071-skin-xml-reference), but I don't see the option for duration either.

Comment: Looking deeper into the JW Player skinning documentation, I think you're out of luck - there's no "duration" XML item available for the playlist: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413071-skin-xml-reference#playlist

Comment: I'm afraid that graphic is a misrepresentation of the playlist. The durations do not show up in the actual playlist - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1428529-display-a-playlist-sidebar

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer are you planning to implement this feature in the future as it was in JWPlayer 5?

Comment: Not that I am aware of I'm afraid.